# Google spreadsheets in-cell string length validation

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I have a column where I want to write down numbers, but the numbers are long, 25 characters, and I could miss type it so at least knowing that I have typed the correct amount of characters would be helpful.

When typing in Google spreadsheets, I can validate the answer of a column within another column by using: '=IF(LEN(B1)=25,B1,"wrong number of digits")'

which means it would return the cell value if has 25 characters, but if its any other amount it will say wrong number, yet I need to use another column...

Is there any way that while I am typing in a cell it would let me proceed if right number of characters or give an error if I have wrong number of characters, **in the same column?**

Comment: You can do this in Excel with a custom number format attached to a conditional formatting rule but Google-Sheets' CF rules do not allow changes to the number format.

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED

Please try a Data, Validation..., rule of:

```
=and(B1>999999999999999,len(B1)=25)
```